# Discord.js v12: Error: The class/prototype returned from the extender function must extend the existing structure class/prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to set up a event handler for my bot. After I add the code and start the bot it outputs the error:
Error:

```
Error: The class/prototype returned from the extender function must extend the existing structure class/prototype (received function ExtendedTextChannel extends TextChannel; expected extension of ExtendedTextChannel).
    at Function.extend (/home/runner/ricebot/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/Structures.js:82:13)
    at module.exports (/home/runner/ricebot/node_modules/discord-buttons/src/index.js:24:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/ricebot/index.js:35:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/ricebot/events/ready.js:1:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at /home/runner/ricebot/index.js:119:18
```

Code:

```js
readdirSync("./events/").forEach((file) => {
  const events = readdirSync("./events/").filter((file) =>
    file.endsWith(".js")
  );

  for(let file of events) {
    let pull = require(`./events/${file}`);

    if(pull.name) {
      client.events.set(pull.name, pull);
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
});
```

The error log leads me to this line 35
`require('discord-buttons')(client);`  and to this line 119 `` let pull = require(`./events/${file}`) ``

This really seems confusing to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of discord.js are you on? Do you have more modules than `discord-buttons`?

Comment: as I stated in the title, I use Discord.js v12, I have many more modules than `discord-buttons`, however discord-buttons is the only module that is required via client like `require("discord-buttons")(client)`.

Comment: Do you have another module that modifies discord.js like discord-reply?

Comment: I am not sure, most likely no.

Comment: @MrMythical don't you know why is that?

Comment: I think 2 modules like that can make problems like this